# How do I print a table from an array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, printing

I have 4 `arrays` that I want to print into a table that looks like this:

```
Item Code, Item, Price, Item Stock
001, Pencil, 10, 738
```

and so on from these 4 `arrays`:

```
item_code = ["Item Code", "001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "010"]

item = ["Item", "Pencil", "Pen", "Eraser", "Paper", "Notebook", "Highlighters", "Card", "Stapler", "Paperclip", "Marker"]

item_price = ["Price", "10", "5", "2", "15", "20", "23", "26", "13", "17", "21"]

item_stock = stock() # This is calculated in another subheading
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for that:

```py
z = zip(item_code, item, item_price, item_stock)
for code, i, price, stock in z:
    print(code, i, price, stock)
```

Comment: or even better: `for i in z: print(*i)`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([item_code[1:], item[1:], item_price[1:]], index=[item_code[0], item[0], item_price[0]]).T
print(df)


  Item Code          Item Price
0       001        Pencil    10
1       002           Pen     5
2       003        Eraser     2
3       004         Paper    15
4       005      Notebook    20
5       006  Highlighters    23
6       007          Card    26
7       008       Stapler    13
8       009     Paperclip    17
9       010        Marker    21
```

Comment: You shouldn't give an answer using a library that he didn't ask for, this can easily be done without it

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple for loop:

```py
for i in range(len(item_code)):
  print(item_code[i], item[i], item_price[i], item_stock[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple for loop, you can do the same for the item_stock

```
item_code = ["Item Code", "001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "010"]

item = ["Item", "Pencil", "Pen", "Eraser", "Paper", "Notebook", "Highlighters", "Card", "Stapler", "Paperclip", "Marker"]

item_price = ["Price", "10", "5", "2", "15", "20", "23", "26", "13", "17", "21"]

for i in range (len(item)):
    
    print(item_code[i],item[i],item_price[i])
```

output:

```
Item Code Item Price
001 Pencil 10
002 Pen 5
003 Eraser 2
004 Paper 15
005 Notebook 20
006 Highlighters 23
007 Card 26
008 Stapler 13
009 Paperclip 17
010 Marker 21
```

Answer (score 0):

More Elegant way to print using f strings

```
item_code = ["Item Code", "001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "008", "009", "010"]

item = ["Item", "Pencil", "Pen", "Eraser", "Paper", "Notebook", "Highlighters", "Card", "Stapler", "Paperclip", "Marker"]

item_price = ["Price", "10", "5", "2", "15", "20", "23", "26", "13", "17", "21"]

item_stock = ["Item Stock", "10", "5", "2", "15", "20", "23", "26", "13", "17", "21"]

for item_code, item, item_price, item_stock in zip(item_code, item, item_price, item_stock):
    print(f'{item_code},{item},{item_price},{item_stock}')

Output:
Item Code,Item,Price,Item Stock
001,Pencil,10,10
002,Pen,5,5
003,Eraser,2,2
004,Paper,15,15
005,Notebook,20,20
006,Highlighters,23,23
007,Card,26,26
008,Stapler,13,13
009,Paperclip,17,17
010,Marker,21,21
```